SPA SEO dynamically updating metatags on node.js express route
I want to dynamically update my meta tags when a POST is received at /source/:uuid
I did:

    app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
         const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] || ''; 
         if (isbot(userAgent)) next();
         else res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/static/index.html'));
    });`

And the route:
   app.post("/source/:uuid", function(req,res){
          const userAgent = req.headers['user-agent'] || ''; 
          if (isbot(userAgent)){
              dbCall(data=>{
                   const raw = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '/static/index.html'))
                   const updated = raw.replace('<title>The New Library of The Atlantis</title>',       "<meta name='description' content="
                   + "'Download" + data.format + " here!'><title>" data.title + "</title>")
                   return res.sendFile(updated)
              })

          }
          else{
               //browser code
          }
    })    

`
But curl and a browser bot checker shows the default meta from index.html
Any help?
I tried placing next() for bots in the * route before the source route and serving a custom index.html with new meta tags for the /source/:uuid POST route, but it's not showing up when I check the bots.

You made a post to "/source/:uuid" and got the original html of index.html? maybe the replace didn't match anything. Also, you're missing a + before data.title in your example.
